# Email content is not refresh when updating the email (New Outlook)

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, new-outlook

I recently started using the new version of Outlook and a third-party application that modifies the body of some (cf : [ms graph documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) of my emails after I receive them. With the new version of Outlook, I have a display problem: the preview display shows the old email content and not the new one.

Solution found :

- By modifying the email folder, it is displayed correctly in the preview.

I checked with a colleague's account and he has no problem.
I compared the settings and there is no difference with him.

Problems :
- I don’t know which parameter is different between my colleague and me.
- I can’t find any setting that invalidates the cache and always displays the new body of the email and not the old one.
The problem only appears on the new Outlook on Windows.

New Outlook version: 1.2023.1129.100 (production) and 1.2023.1212.100.
Client version: 20231201002.05. (edited)

[image: The new content is not displayed]

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the client, from version `1.2023.1215.200` the refresh seems to work.